# Move button around form

Tags: c#, controls, move

I am looking to move a button around a form in this motion

```
|<----------
|           ^
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
V---------->|
```

one step at a time (every time it's clicked)

Here is my code so far (doesn't move correctly):

```
if (btnClicker.Location.X > this.ClientSize.Width - btnClicker.Width)
      btnClicker.Location = new Point(btnClicker.Location.X, btnClicker.Location.Y + 1);
else if (btnClicker.Location.X < btnClicker.Width)
      btnClicker.Location = new Point(btnClicker.Location.X+1, btnClicker.Location.Y);
else if (btnClicker.Location.Y > this.ClientSize.Height - btnClicker.Height)
      btnClicker.Location = new Point(btnClicker.Location.X, btnClicker.Location.Y - 1);
else if (btnClicker.Location.Y < this.ClientSize.Height - btnClicker.Height)
      btnClicker.Location = new Point(btnClicker.Location.X - 1, btnClicker.Location.Y);
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt move correctly?

Comment: It doesn't move in the desired pattern/direction.

Comment: Where will the initial position of the button be? On the top-left corner of the form? If not then which edge of the form do you want the button to reach first and then start your motion? Also do you want your button to traverse across the edges of the form?

Comment: I want the button to start in the button center.
I want it to have a gap of about 5 pixels from the form border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written this code for you. Check it out. I have tested it partially from my side and it looks good but test it thoroughly at your end. Tweak it as per your requirement.

```
bool _isFirst = true;
bool _reachedBottomRight = false;
bool _reachedTopRight = false;
int _increDecreValue = 1;
int StartXPos = 5;
int StartYPos = 5;

private void btnClicker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (_isFirst)
    {
        //Set the start location of the button. This can be any position you want
        btnClicker.Location = new Point(StartXPos, StartYPos);
        _isFirst = false;
    }

    if (btnClicker.Location.Y < this.ClientSize.Height - btnClicker.Height && !_reachedBottomRight)
        btnClicker.Location = new Point(btnClicker.Location.X, btnClicker.Location.Y + _increDecreValue);
    else if (btnClicker.Location.X < this.ClientSize.Width - btnClicker.Width && !_reachedTopRight)
        btnClicker.Location = new Point(btnClicker.Location.X + _increDecreValue, btnClicker.Location.Y);
    else if (btnClicker.Location.Y > StartYPos)
    {
        btnClicker.Location = new Point(btnClicker.Location.X, btnClicker.Location.Y - _increDecreValue);
        _reachedBottomRight = true;
    }
    else if (btnClicker.Location.X > StartXPos)
    {
        btnClicker.Location = new Point(btnClicker.Location.X - _increDecreValue, btnClicker.Location.Y);
        _reachedTopRight = true;
    }

    if (btnClicker.Location.X <= StartXPos && btnClicker.Location.Y <= StartYPos)
    {
        _reachedBottomRight = false;
        _reachedTopRight = false;
    }
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for then please comment.

Hope this helps.